# Is posible do after build or have multiple build steps with webpack?

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack

I have webpack frontend application that have config file (config/default.json). I read this with config-webpack. My config file should change between environments (staging/production/etc)

I have CI pipeline that build my js code, minimize and package in docker image of nginx to be published in docker registry (inmutable|agnostic of my config file).

My docker container must be initialize env key with execution value

```
ENVIRONMENT=staging|production|stress
```

In docker container i have connection to secrets store and retrieve config data for my execution ENVIRONMENT.

Doing all the build on container start is expensive.

I need post process my build to attach `config/default.json` to webpack bundle. No build all my project.

Comment: If you can build on container start, you can always perform that step when building the container. You just need to figure out what that step entails. Probably a `COPY` operation?

Comment: The question is: ¿How add my config file after build and read it with config-webpack?

Comment: It is not possible to add config file after build and read it with config-webpack. JS build depends on webpack config. You'll have to build multiple docker images for different environments, if prebuilding JS.